# How to delete a specific string in a text file?

Tags: java, file-io

How can I delete a specific string in a text file?

Comment: What do you have so far, and how doesn't it work?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Locate the file.

```
File file = new File("/path/to/file.txt");
```

Create a temporary file (otherwise you've to read everything into Java's memory first).

```
File temp = File.createTempFile("file", ".txt", file.getParentFile());
```

Determine the charset.

```
String charset = "UTF-8";
```

Determine the string you'd like to delete.

```
String delete = "foo";
```

Open the file for reading.

```
BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(new FileInputStream(file), charset));
```

Open the temp file for writing.

```
PrintWriter writer = new PrintWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(new FileOutputStream(temp), charset));
```

Read the file line by line.

```
for (String line; (line = reader.readLine()) != null;) {
    // ...
}
```

Delete the string from the line.

```
    line = line.replace(delete, "");
```

Write it to temp file.

```
    writer.println(line);
```

Close the reader and writer (preferably in the `finally` block).

```
reader.close();
writer.close();
```

Delete the file.

```
file.delete();
```

Rename the temp file.

```
temp.renameTo(file);
```

#### See also:

- [The Java Tutorials - Lesson: basic I/O](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/io/)

Comment: +1 - though it is a bit more complicated if the String you are trying to delete spans line boundaries.

Comment: It is so tedious, why is it quicker in SQL. quick to scan through but time consuming to edit.

Comment: @kyleengland: because a text file is not a relational database.