# Removing stop words is not tokenizing correctly

Tags: java, string

I using java program to remove stop words in a word file. But my stop word removal not removing special characters. And I want to remove all the stop words and other unnecessary words,special characters and numbers from the file.

How to improve this code

```
             {                                         
    String[] stopwords ={"a", "about", "above", "above", "across", "after", "afterwards", "again", "against", "all", "almost", 
            "alone", "along", "already", "also","although","always","am","among", "amongst", "amoungst", "amount",  "an", "and", 
            "another", "any","anyhow","anyone","anything","anyway", "anywhere", "are", "around", "as",  "at", "back","be","became", 
            "because","become","becomes", "becoming", "been", "before", "beforehand", "behind", "being", "below", "beside", "besides", 
            "between", "beyond", "bill", "both", "bottom","but", "by", "call", "can", "cannot", "cant", "co", "con", "could", "couldnt",
            "cry", "de", "describe", "detail", "do", "done", "down", "due", "during", "each", "eg", "eight", "either", "eleven","else",
            "elsewhere", "empty", "enough", "etc", "even", "ever", "every", "everyone", "everything", "everywhere", "except", "few", 
            "fifteen", "fify", "fill", "find", "fire", "first", "five", "for", "former", "formerly", "forty", "found", "four", "from", 
            "front", "full", "further", "get", "give", "go", "had", "has", "hasnt",
            "have", "he", "hence", "her", "here", "hereafter", "hereby", "herein", "hereupon", "hers", "herself", 
            "him", "himself", "his", "how", "however", "hundred", "ie", "if", "in", "inc", "indeed", "interest", "into", 
            "is", "it", "its", "itself", "keep", "last", "latter", "latterly", "least", "less", "ltd", "made", "many", 
            "may", "me", "meanwhile", "might", "mill", "mine", "more", "moreover", "most", "mostly", "move", "much", "must", 
            "my", "myself", "name", "namely", "neither", "never", "nevertheless", "next", "nine", "no", "nobody", "none", 
            "noone", "nor", "not", "nothing", "now", "nowhere", "of", "off", "often", "on", "once", "one", "only", "onto", 
            "or", "other", "others", "otherwise", "our", "ours", "ourselves", "out", "over", "own","part", "per", "perhaps",
            "please", "put", "rather", "re", "same", "see", "seem", "seemed", "seeming", "seems", "serious", "several", "she",
            "should", "show", "side", "since", "sincere", "six", "sixty", "so", "some", "somehow", "someone", "something", 
            "sometime", "sometimes", "somewhere", "still", "such", "system", "take", "ten", "than", "that", "the", "their", 
            "them", "themselves", "then", "thence", "there", "thereafter", "thereby", "therefore", "therein", "thereupon", 
            "these", "they", "thickv", "thin", "third", "this", "those", "though", "three", "through", "throughout", "thru", 
            "thus", "to", "together", "too", "top", "toward", "towards", "twelve", "twenty", "two", "un", "under", "until", 
            "up", "upon", "us", "very", "via", "was", "we", "well", "were", "what", "whatever", "when", "whence", "whenever",
            "where", "whereafter", "whereas", "whereby", "wherein", "whereupon", "wherever", "whether", "which", "while", 
            "whither", "who", "whoever", "whole", "whom", "whose", "why", "will", "with", "within", "without", "would", "yet",
            "you", "your", "yours", "yourself", "yourselves","1","2","3","4","5","6","7","8","9","10","1.","2.","3.","4.","5.","6.","11",
            "7.","8.","9.","12","13","14","A","B","C","D","E","F","G","H","I","J","K","L","M","N","O","P","Q","R","S","T","U","V","W","X","Y","Z",
            "terms","CONDITIONS","conditions","values","interested.","care","sure",".","!","@","#","$","%","^","&","*","(",")","{","}","[","]",":",";",",","<",".",">","/","?","_","-","+","=",
            "a","b","c","d","e","f","g","h","i","j","k","l","m","n","o","p","q","r","s","t","u","v","w","x","y","z",
            "contact","grounds","buyers","tried","said,","plan","value","principle.","forces","sent:","is,","was","like",
            "discussion","tmus","diffrent.","layout","area.","thanks","thankyou","hello","bye","rise","fell","fall","psqft.","http://","km","miles"};

    try
    {
        Scanner fip1=new Scanner(new File("c:/removewords.txt"));
        FileOutputStream out=new FileOutputStream("c:/StopWords.txt");

      while(fip1.hasNext())
      {
          int flag=1;
          String s1=fip1.next();
          s1=s1.toLowerCase();
          for(int i=0;i<stopwords.length;i++){
              if(s1.equals(stopwords[i]))
                  {
                  flag=0;
                  }
          }
          if(flag!=0)
          {
              System.out.println(s1);


              PrintStream p=new PrintStream(out);
              p.println(s1);   
          }



      }
      JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"STOP WORD REMOVAL IS DONE");        
      }
      catch(Exception e){
          System.err.println("cannot read file");
      }
}
```

Comment: Reduce the string array!! We get it using small array too.

Comment: You should probably be using a Set instead of a String array to make the comparison a more reasonable speed.

Comment: Use a **`boolean`** instead of an `int` for **boolean value** (`flag`).

Comment: how to store these words in a Set<String>?

Comment: look at this for a way of removing from a file http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5360209/how-to-delete-a-specific-string-in-a-text-file

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe you could have a look at [Apache Lucene](http://lucene.apache.org/) and its [Stop Filter](http://lucene.apache.org/core/old_versioned_docs/versions/3_5_0/api/all/org/apache/lucene/analysis/StopFilter.html):

```java
// input string
String input = "Please remove my stop words!";

// tokenize the input string
TokenStream tokenStream = new ClassicTokenizer(Version.LUCENE_35, new StringReader(input));
// remove stop words
tokenStream = new StopFilter(Version.LUCENE_35, tokenStream, EnglishAnalyzer.getDefaultStopSet());

// retrieve the remaining tokens
Set<String> tokens = new HashSet<String>();
CharTermAttribute token = tokenStream.getAttribute(CharTermAttribute.class);
try {
    while (tokenStream.incrementToken()) {
        tokens.add(token.toString());
    }
} catch (IOException e) {
    // log
}

// tokens contains only non-stop words from now on
```

Comment: this is used to remove stop words? or store the stopwords?

Comment: To remove them from the input string. This is what you needed, am I wrong?