# File handling program in java

Tags: java, replace, text-files, edit, file-handling

[enter image description here][1]I am trying to do a java program that reads and edits (add/remove/replace) a specific line in a text file. I was thinking of doing it with a switch-case statement for the choices.. for example:

[1] read file ---  this shows the whole content
[2] add content --- the user will enter a text and it will save it into the text file 
[3] replace line --- enters line # and shows the content and the user replaces it
[4] remove line --- enters line # and removes the content
etc...

is it possible to create a text file and make all of these choices into a single java file? I was also thinking that if i will make this using switch case, i will use methods on each choices to perform its tasks. I'm a bit confused about the flow of this program so it would be helpful if you guys can give me steps or tips in making this? I'm quite a noob at this and I really need help

[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/On2S7.png --- i was just starting to do this program and this is my idea

Comment: Have you tried anything so far?

Comment: I was just starting to make this program. i have this idea but i dont know if this will work so i was asking for some opinions or suggestions

Comment: Possible, yes?  Straightforward, no.

Answer (score 0):

Yeah its possible i have done the same thing making a School project in `c++`. 
Where you can enter the info about the student, and also `edit`, `delete`, `view`, `seek` the specific content, `delete` the entire content.

For writing in file

```
BufferedWriter write = Files.newBufferedWriter(Paths.get(enter path of the file));
```

Reading from file

```
String content = new String(Files.readAllBytes(Paths.get("enter path")));
```

replacing a specific content
    [java replace specific string in textfile](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23466179/java-replace-specific-string-in-textfile)

deleting content
[How to delete a specific string in a text file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5360209/how-to-delete-a-specific-string-in-a-text-file)